# Kendo UI Professional for school project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, widget, kendo-grid, javascript-framework

I am preparing my final school project and I have same questions about licensing of Kendo UI.

1. Does Kendo have any free school license?
2. Can I use Kendo UI Professional Trial for that project or is it illegal? Kendo UI Core is not enough because I need more advanced components like grid, charts and so on...
3. If not, can you suggest me any similar framework for free, with nice bootstrap look?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, only free version is [Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core) (for comparassion here is good [list](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison)).
2. If your school project will not get any reward I believe you can use trial, however this licensing problems is better to ask directly Telerik team (because 100 people - 100 different answers)
3. Free frameworks for grids is for example [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) - they are easy to use, powerful and free (under [MIT license](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/)). For charts I have good experience with [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) - again under MIT.